# Parts of speech 'Both'

Tags: parts-of-speech

> Max and John  **both** jumped on the sofa.

In this context, is *both* a **pronoun**?  What I am struggling with is what kind of pronoun is it?

**Q:** Is **both** a possessive or personal pronoun?

Comment: _Both_ is a quantifier, which is a type of determiner, like articles and numbers. _Both_ is a suppletive variant of *_all two_, which is ungrammatical in English. It really modifies _Max and John_ in this sentence, but like _each_ (and unlike _every_), _both_ can undergo Quantifier-float, which niches certain quantifiers into an adverb position before the verb, as here. Note that this is equivalent to _Both Max and John jumped on the sofa_.

Comment: so does this mean that in this context 'both' is  an adverb?

Comment: No, it's not a pronoun but a 'universal' determinative functioning as a quantificational adjunct in clause structure, not NP structure. This is evident from the fact that when the verb is an auxiliary it preferentially follows rather than precedes it, as in "Max and John had both jumped on the sofa". Note also the possibility of inserting an adjunct after "Max and John" and before the quantificational adjunct, as in "Max and John certainly both jumped on the sofa". The adjunct "both" has the form of a fused-head NP.